# How to identify the specific true or false value from json assertion using jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, response, extractor

The requirement is we have to identify "elements" and then check if its true or false.

```html
{
    "first": {
        "second": [
            {
                "element": 1,
                "elementrec": null,
                "enabled": true,
                "rec": null
            },
            {
               "element": 2,
                "elementrec": null,
                "enabled": false,
                "rec": null
            },
            {
                "element": 3,
                "elementrec": [
                    "3"
                ],
                "enabled": true,
                "rec": [
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        }
      ]
    } 
}
```

Above 3 element has either true or false. Would like to identify all 3 elements for true or false using different json assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "identify", there are too many possible options so I'll come up with the shortest one:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).first.second.each { item ->
       log.info('Element: ' + item.element + ', enabled: ' + item.enabled)
   }
   ```
3. Run your test
4. In [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file you will see "elements" with their "enabled" status

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I mean if the enable=true for element 1 then the test is pass. I donot have to check all elements at once, just 1 at a time. Kind of assertion I want to use it to get expected true/false.

Comment: Then use [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) configured like https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Qv0.png. Just in case textual JSONPath representation: `first.second[?(@.element == '1')].enabled` and reference: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: thank you so much, I was trying the same syntax since long but was missing filter "?(@" . worked this time!